# Retrieving Data from Multiple tables duplicates and creates additional duplicate objects when grouping by

Tags: arrays, laravel, object, foreach

I am using this foreach to get data from Orders by searching the DocketList I am getting the expected data but it creates additional objects!

```
$spreadreport = [];
$getOrderList = DocketList::groupBy('order_list_id')->whereBetween('docket_date', $request->input('data'))->pluck('order_list_id');
foreach ($getOrderList as $listId) {
$getOrderId = OrderList::where('id', $listId)->pluck('order_id');
foreach ($getOrderId as $orderId) {
$spreadreport[] = Order::where('id', $orderId)->get()->groupBy('order_delivery_zone');
}
```

Below i have attached the data i get at the moment. The group by order delivery zone should not repeat as it the same for both the data i search. I don't understand why i get two objects when i am expecting one.. **both order 269 and 270 should be under the group by 2 please help!**

[image]

Comment: DId you try running `groupBy` before `get`? Try this code `$spreadreport[] = Order::where('id', $orderId)->groupBy('order_delivery_zone')->get();`

Comment: Yes. I got a symtax error!

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: It was a syntax error only mate

Comment: Can you show me what code did you put? Did you put exactly `$spreadreport[] = Order::where('id', $orderId)->groupBy('order_delivery_zone')->get();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue.
This is my controller.

```
 $getOrderList = DocketList::groupBy('order_list_id')->whereBetween('docket_date', $request->input('data'))->pluck('order_list_id');
            $getOrderId = OrderList::whereIn('id', $getOrderList)->pluck('order_id');
            $getProductListId = OrderListProducts::groupBy('order_list_id')->whereIn('order_list_id', $getOrderList)->pluck('order_list_id');
            $getOrderProductId = OrderList::whereIn('id', $getProductListId)->pluck('order_id');
            $orders = Order::whereIn('id', $getOrderId)->WhereIn('id', $getOrderProductId)->get();
```

and created a relationship products to get the data as i want

```
   public function products()
    {
        $products = [];
        foreach ($this->order_list as $order_list) {
            foreach ($order_list->order_list_products as $product) {
                $products[] = $product->product_mix_id;
            }
        }

        return $products;
    }
```